# How to find blocked queries in Azure SQL dataware house?

Tags: data-warehouse, azure-synapse, warehouse

Is there is any way to check blocked queries in Azure Data warehouse?? In my monitoring tool it's shows two blocked queries during morning session. I need to find which queries are blocking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at the DMV sys.dm_pdw_waits. There is an example in this article, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-manage-monitor/#monitor-waiting-queries.